# Did Libya's Central Bank offer loans at 0% interest?

Tags: africa, banking, gaddafi, democracy

I just watched [The illuminati Exposed By Muammar Gaddafi](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gQzFjac1A1M). It's a really good watch (especially for us skeptics), but at one point they said that the reason Muammar al-Gaddafi was **overthrown** was, **not because he was a bad, unpopular or corrupt leader** but because he lead Libya to a "golden age" where the Libyan Central Bank offered **loans at 0% interest**. Apparently, the Illuminati, lead by the Rothschild banking empire, couldn't allow 0% interest loans because that would undermine their primary income (after world domination).

Obviously, we can't prove or disprove the illuminati here, but did the Libyan Central Bank offer loans at 0% interest?

Comment: Do they specify *how* 0% interest loans would undermine modern economies as we know them?

Comment: @BrendanLong Sorry, the video didn't actually say that. It said the Rothschild Group (sometimes called the illuminati) couldn't allow a bank to offer interest free loans. And the first thing the "rebels" did when they took power was make a new central bank (with loan with interest).

Comment: So, did I miss them invading [Switzerland](http://www.ft.com/cms/s/0/b1afca6a-c4d1-11e0-9c4d-00144feabdc0.html#axzz2I8HokTIU) too?

Comment: Oups. I guess my 0% loan from Citibank makes me the next Illuminati targe....[carrier signal lost]

Comment: You say:  `we can't prove or disprove the illuminati here` Really?  That's a pretty bold claim.

Comment: @Brightblades, you think the illuminati doesn't control Skeptics.stackexchange.com? They're everywhere, they own everything especially the internet!

Comment: "but at one point they said that the reason Muammar al-Gaddafi was overthrown was, not because he was a bad, unpopular or corrupt leader but because he lead Libya to a "golden age" where the Libyan Central Bank offered loans at 0% interest." Not true, it says explicitly the main reason was his challenge to the petro dollar, the only reason the US dollar is being propped up.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

1. Libya's entire GDP in 2000s fluctuated between $30B and $100B. ([source](https://www.google.com/publicdata/explore?ds=d5bncppjof8f9_&met_y=ny_gdp_mktp_cd&idim=country:LBY&dl=en&hl=en&q=libya%20gdp))

   Libya's Central Bank assets in 2011 were estimated to be $25bn (since then, doubled due to finding another $20 odd billion in assets - [source](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:_POATqKrA0MJ:www.ft.com/cms/s/0/8a34f66e-e474-11e0-92a3-00144feabdc0.html%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us#axzz2I9UM61KV)).

   The world banking system that has many trillions of assets. A list of private banks' assets is [here](http://www.relbanks.com/worlds-top-banks/assets), just the biggest ones add up to ~$80 Trillion; major central banks seem to add up to $10 Trillion ([source](http://www.cumber.com/content/misc/G4_Charts.pdf))).

   In order to imagine that the ability to loan out a paltry $50bn at 0% has any measurable effect on said world banking system, one would need some very very very good imagination and not even a rudimentary knowledge of finance.
2. Japan had a ZIRP ([Zero interest-rate policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_interest-rate_policy) ) for the better part of 2 decades during "Lost decade" period. Japanese GDP is $4-6Trillion ([source](https://www.google.com/publicdata/explore?ds=d5bncppjof8f9_&met_y=ny_gdp_mktp_cd&idim=country:JPN&dl=en&hl=en&q=japan%20gdp)).

   I have somehow failed to notice a coalition of Illuminati Bankers invading Japan in the last 20 years. I clearly need better drugs.

Leaving aside the drug induced conspiracy ravings, Libya did, indeed offer loans for house purchasing or construction in Islamic loan's conditions, that is zero interest rate. ([source](http://businessafrica.net/africabiz/arcvol2/email123.php)). This is not surprising given that [**Sharia prohibits usury**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_banking).

Comment: you gravatar suggests this is an Illuminati cover up answer. also you don't mention if Libya actually had said policies

Comment: @Ryathal - added...

Comment: The edit has greatly improved the answer, but it isn't clear how the key source for 0% interest knows that (there are a lot of general references provided, but nothing specific.)

Comment: After reading the zero interest rate source, I have to retract my upvote. The source appears to be poorly sourced, and makes extremely unbelievable claims (see [my question](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/29967/do-libyan-brides-get-a-usd-90000-dowry-from-the-government)).

Comment: I'd add that many nations have 0% interest rates because they're under Sharia law.

Comment: @PointlessSpike Sharia compliant banking is a bit more involved than 0% interest rate.  After all, no bank can turn a profit from a 0% loan - so, with the potential exception of central banks they will not offer loans on those terms.

Comment: Not *solely* on those terms, no, but they will likely have loans, and they won't have any interest on them.

Comment: What they sometimes have is similar to the Medieval method of avoiding charges of usury, holding fees and the like.